# Converting typescript alias into interface with union type

Tags: typescript

How do I convert this `type alias` into interface?

```
type Color = 'RED' | 'GREEN' | 'BLACK';
const color: Color = 'RED';
```

My intuition was to use but its wrong.

```
interface Color {
  [item: 'RED' | 'GREEN' | 'BLACK']: string;
}
const color: Color = 'RED'
```

What I want to do is replace type with interface.
So basically the variable with type of that interface can only be assigned one of these values, 'RED','GREEN' or 'BLUE'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type aliasses and interafecs are not interchangeable.

Sometimes, if the type alias can be resolved to a simple object type, the two are very close in what you can do with them.

If the type alias is a union then you can't change it to an interface

Comment: I do not want to use `type` I want to convert `type` into interface. i apologise if question was not clear.

Comment: @alt255 The `type` and the interface are pretty much equivalent in this case .. you can do `interface ColorData extends Record<Color, string> { }` if you really want an interface

Comment: after doing `ColorData extends Record<Color, string> { }` this assignment does not work.
const cd: ColorData = 'RED'

Comment: @alt255 ok, now I understand what you want, there is no way to replace a type alias that contains a union with an interface. Why would you want to do that, what it the reason for this ?

Comment: no particular reason. I was under impression that `type` alias and `interface` are totally interchangeable.

Comment: @alt255 They are not. There are cases where a they are interchangeable, mostly when the type alias can be expanded to an concerte object type, but usually they are not.

Comment: ok thanks can you update your answer to reflect that it's not possible so I mark it answered.

Comment: @alt255 changed the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert an **Union Type** into an **Interface** using a [generic interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html).

*This is a type union:*

```js
type Color = 'RED' | 'GREEN' | 'BLACK';
const color: Color = 'RED';
```

*This is it converted to an interface:*

```
interface Color<Label1="RED", Label2="GREEN", Label3="BLACK"> {
    name: Label1 | Label2 | Label3
}

const color: Color = { name: "RED" } // ok, static checked
```

Although, based on your *particular* use case, would you prefer to use just an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html). Like this:

```
enum Color {
    RED = 'RED',
    GREEN = 'GREEN',
    BLACK = 'BLACK'
}

const color: Color = Color.RED // ok, static checked ---> color = 'RED'
```